# How can update data range of combo chart by Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

In a Google Sheet, i have 2 charts: a Combo chart, a Pie Chart

Data Range of `Combo chart`:  `C51:O57,Q51:AB58,AD51:AO58,AQ51:BB58,BD51:BO58,BQ51:CB58,CD51:CO58`
and Combine Range is `Horizontally`

Data Range of `Pie Chart`: `A51:A55,CQ51:CQ55`
and Combine Range is `Horizontally`

I want update Data Range of 2 Charts:

`Combo chart`: add Range "CQ51:DB58"

`Pie Chart`:  replace "CQ51:CQ55" to "DD51:DD55"

I had try this code:

`Pie Chart` update ok.

`Combo chart` occur error: `Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id`

```
    var oSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    var sheet_Des=oSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var charts = sheet_Des.getCharts();

    //Pie Chart 
   var chart = charts[1];
   var ranges = chart.getRanges();
   var newRange=sheet_Des.getRange(51,108 ,5,1);
  // var  rangename=newRange.getA1Notation();
   var chart = chart.modify()
          .removeRange(ranges[1])          
          .addRange(newRange)
          .build();
   sheet_Des.updateChart(chart);

    //Combo Chart 
    chart = charts[0];
    ranges = chart.getRanges();
    newRange=sheet_Des.getRange(51,95 ,8,12);
    // var  rangename2=newRange.getA1Notation();
    chart = chart.modify()          
          .addRange(newRange)
          .build();       
    sheet_Des.updateChart(chart);
```

Why can't update data range of `Combo chart`?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your script and I got the same error. This seems to be an issue, I found similar [reports](https://issuetracker.google.com/183272766) on Google's Issue Tracker, [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/179701683) is another sample. You can add comments on both issues to ask for updates or check if someone else found a workarond.

A workaround that worked for me, is deleting the chart and creating a new one, I used the following script:

```js
function createChart() {
  var oSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet_Des=oSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var charts = sheet_Des.getCharts();

  //Pie Chart 
  var chart = charts[1];
  var ranges = chart.getRanges();
  var newRange=sheet_Des.getRange(51,108 ,5,1);
  // var  rangename=newRange.getA1Notation();
  var chart = chart.modify()
    .removeRange(ranges[1])          
    .addRange(newRange)
    .build();
  sheet_Des.updateChart(chart);

  //Combo Chart 
  chart = charts[0];
  var options = charts[0].getOptions().get('title'); //If you want to copy some options from the Combo Chart before deleting it, you need to get each option in a separate variable
  ranges = chart.getRanges();
  newRange=sheet_Des.getRange(51,95 ,8,12);
  // var  rangename2=newRange.getA1Notation();
  sheet_Des.removeChart(chart);
  chart = sheet_Des.newChart()
    .asComboChart()
    .addRange(newRange)
    .setOption('title',options) //Set the options that you want (title, width, height, etc)
    .build()
  sheet_Des.insertChart(chart.modify().setPosition(43,6,0,0).build()) //Adjust the position where you want to create the Chart
}
```

**UPDATE**

[This](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate?apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%22XXXX%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22updateChartSpec%22%3A%7B%22chartId%22%3A12345%2C%22spec%22%3A%7B%22basicChart%22%3A%7B%22chartType%22%3A%22COMBO%22%2C%22domains%22%3A%5B%7B%22domain%22%3A%7B%22sourceRange%22%3A%7B%22sources%22%3A%5B%7B%22startRowIndex%22%3A22%2C%22endRowIndex%22%3A28%2C%22startColumnIndex%22%3A0%2C%22endColumnIndex%22%3A1%7D%5D%7D%7D%7D%5D%2C%22series%22%3A%5B%7B%22series%22%3A%7B%22sourceRange%22%3A%7B%22sources%22%3A%5B%7B%22startRowIndex%22%3A22%2C%22endRowIndex%22%3A28%2C%22startColumnIndex%22%3A1%2C%22endColumnIndex%22%3A2%7D%5D%7D%7D%2C%22targetAxis%22%3A%22LEFT_AXIS%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22COLUMN%22%7D%2C%7B%22series%22%3A%7B%22sourceRange%22%3A%7B%22sources%22%3A%5B%7B%22startRowIndex%22%3A22%2C%22endRowIndex%22%3A28%2C%22startColumnIndex%22%3A2%2C%22endColumnIndex%22%3A3%7D%5D%7D%7D%2C%22targetAxis%22%3A%22LEFT_AXIS%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22COLUMN%22%7D%2C%7B%22series%22%3A%7B%22sourceRange%22%3A%7B%22sources%22%3A%5B%7B%22startRowIndex%22%3A22%2C%22endRowIndex%22%3A28%2C%22startColumnIndex%22%3A3%2C%22endColumnIndex%22%3A4%7D%5D%7D%7D%2C%22targetAxis%22%3A%22RIGHT_AXIS%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22LINE%22%7D%5D%7D%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D&apix=true) is a sample with the Sheets API. You can click in the `JAVASCRIPT` tab to get an idea of how you make the request in Apps Script.

**Note:** If you access the Sheets API using Apps Script, you will have to enable the Advanced Sheets Service.

## References:

- [newChart()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#newchart)
- [insertChart(chart)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertchartchart)
- [Combo chart configuration options](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/chart-configuration-options#combo-chart-configuration-options)
- [UpdateChartSpecRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatechartspecrequest)
- [Enable advanced services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)

Comment: Can update combo chart by API?

Comment: Yes, you can update through the API, personally I feel that doing it through the API is more complicated, I added a quick sample with "Try this method" in the answer above. Basically you will have to use the `spreadsheets.get` method to get the ID of the chart you want to update and copy other data that you want to add in the `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` request body.